# Need to design showed HTML (Div) with settings icon

Tags: html, css, layout

I need help in the design below showed HTML with settings icon like shown.

[image]

Comment: There's many ways to go about this. You could have two divs with the smaller one on the right having a `clip-path` set. You can generate one at https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ . For the settings and arrow icon I would recommend something from https://fontawesome.com/icons?from=io . The question is a little unspecific so I hope this helps.

Comment: Step 1. Share what you've tried.

Comment: @jkofsie - It would be great if you can provide html and css demo for my requirement.

Comment: Kindly add your html/css code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.polydiv {
  clip-path: polygon(48% 0, 100% 0, 100% 30%, 83% 43%, 83% 77%, 0 77%, 0 0);
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  padding:5px;
  position:relative;
  background: #ccc;
}

.right_pos {
  position: absolute;
  right: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom:6px;
}
ul li i {
 color:#ffffff;
 font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="polydiv">
clip-path property used
  <ul class="right_pos">
    <li><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i>
      <li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-backward"></i>
          <li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

kindly check if this is helpful to you...

Comment: IT works fine for chrome and firefox. But it doesn't work in IE11. Is there any workaround for IE?